# How to keep beaconservice active after stopping local service in app which implements BeaconConsumer

Tags: android, service, altbeacon

I am using Alt **Beacons library** in my android app for detecting beacons. I have used a *service* in my app which calls API takes `json response` which has `UUID` and then bind the beacon *service* in the local service. Everything works fine. The beacons get detected in Ranging. But *when I stop the local service I get following error*:

> 11-26 14:25:42.213: E/ActivityThread(25940): Service
>   com.example.service.GetRegionService has leaked ServiceConnection
>   org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager$1@41faac98 that was originally
>   bound here

and the **beacon service stops working**. How can I make the beacon service work in `background` when I stop my own service which implements `BeaconConsumer`.

Would appreciate any help on the same.